# Can I power a 2021 iMac via any of its USB-C ports?

Tags: imac, usb

Can I use third party USB-C wall adapters to power a 2021 iMac via any of its four USB-C ports?

What is the minimum wattage required with USB-C, in order to operate the iMac at normal and performance CPU frequencies?

Comment: I do believe that the USB-C ports on *any* iMac are not where it gets its power from, you **have** to use the power adapter that it comes with.

Answer (score 3):

Neither the 2021 iMac, nor any iMac, nor any desktop Mac that Apple has ever released, contains the **necessary electronic circuitry** that is required to allow powering the computer from any source other than its mains power inlet. Adding this would entail additional design **complexity**, **PCB space**, **QA resource allocation**, and, most of all, **cost**, all for a device that is marketed for the low end of the market. Apple sees no reason to do this, and, consequently, it hasn't.

[That being said, your question is a reasonable one to ask: Recent iMacs are designed with **Thermal Design Points** (**TDPs**) comparable to MacBook Pros and therefore need to keep their power requirements low enough to meet those numbers. The 2021 iMac uses a **143 W** power supply, which is about 1.5x that of the 96 W supply that the 16" MacBook Pro uses. This is beyond the 100 W maximum power that can be supplied by the current USB Power Delivery 3.0 standard, but is within the 240 W of the recently announced (May 2021) 3.1 standard.]